# Can the product of "Any number of prime numbers" be same as "Any other product of prime numbers".

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Example:

3*5 = 15, which is not possible to obtain as a product of any other 2 or 3 primes.
Will this stand good for higher primes as well?

Comment: Did you try to prove that it will stand using induction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will hold. The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic says that any integer greater than $1$ may be factorised **uniquely** as a product of prime numbers.

For example,

$$15 = 3 \cdot 5$$

There is simply no other way to multiply **any** collection of primes together to get $15$ (apart from reordering it to $5 \cdot 3$ of course, but that's considered the same).

The same is true for any integer greater than $1$. For $759$:

$$759 = 3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23$$

There is no other way to express $759$ as a product of primes. Not as $2$ of them, $3$ of them, or any number of them. This is the only way to do it. It's really quite wonderful, I think.

Comment: How do you factor the integer $-15$ as a product of primes? And what about the integer zero?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Haha, I was fully aware of that bludgeon, but wanted to keep it simple for the OP. Nonetheless, you're correct, so I'll fix it :)

Comment: Good – though I think you've gone one step too far, as the integer 1 can be factored uniquely as a product of primes, namely, as the empty product of primes. But perhaps there is something to be said for not scaring away the novices.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - I think the empty product is just something of a convention to make the theorem easier to state. Similar to how $1$ is not called a prime. Explaining the notion of "empty product" would complicate my answer, but not add anything to it. Simplicity is good, especially for a novice. Technical correctedness even more so, which is why I took in your fist suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question! The answer is that factorization into a product of primes is indeed unique (i.e., no two different products of primes yield the same result), but that uniqueness (part of the so-called "Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic"), although indeed true, is NOT as *obviously* true as many people naively reason it to be! It actually takes some significant thought to grasp a valid argument for why such uniqueness is guaranteed.

One way to see it is true is by first using the extended Euclidean algorithm to establish Bézout's identity (that for any $x$ and $y$, there are some $a$ and $b$ such that $ax + by$ divides both $x$ and $y$; in particular, this guarantees that any values have a greatest common divisor divisible by all their other common divisors). From this, one can reason to Euclid's lemma (that a prime $p$ divides a product $xy$ if and only if $p$ divides at least one of the factors $x$ or $y$), and from this, the uniqueness of prime factorization follows readily.